# Basic controller on Spring boot giving 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to create a basic controller on spring boot but I get:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Dec 14 21:21:36 ART 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404).
>
> No message available

error. I have the controller in a subpackage of the package where the application is located as it should be.

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

HomeController.java:

```
package com.example.demo.home;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

}
```

DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2018-12-14 21:16:46.179  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-BMTCH27 with PID 5420 (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\Project\target\classes started by Usuario in C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\Project)
2018-12-14 21:16:46.179  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-14 21:16:51.395  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-12-14 21:16:51.433  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-14 21:16:51.433  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2018-12-14 21:16:51.464  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_192/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_192/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_192/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop;;.]
2018-12-14 21:16:51.871  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2018-12-14 21:16:51.871  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-14 21:16:51.871  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5489 ms
2018-12-14 21:16:52.449  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-14 21:16:52.959  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-14 21:16:52.975  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 8.155 seconds (JVM running for 9.247)
2018-12-14 21:17:00.448  INFO 5420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-14 21:17:00.448  INFO 5420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-14 21:17:00.462  INFO 5420 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 13 ms
```

[Folder strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TszO.png)

Comment: You app is a war or jar because i do not see anywhere packaging jar or war ?

Comment: Try my answer and let us know !

Comment: @TinyOS the comment you made about adding a dependency was right. Can you please post it again?

Answer (score 1):

It can be  from @Controller annotion. Please change it to `@RestController`

From spring boot documentation  https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

In Spring’s approach to building RESTful web services, HTTP requests are handled by a controller. These components are easily identified by the @RestController annotation, and the GreetingController below handles GET requests for /greeting by returning a new instance of the Greeting class:

Answer (score 1):

`@Controller` annotation represents the Spring MVC Controller. If you mark your class with `@Controller` annotation you have to put `@ResponseBody` on the handler methods.

On the other side, `@RestController` annotation is a specialized version of `@Controller` which adds `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotation automatically so there is no need to add `@ResponseBody` to our handler methods.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

}
```

or

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For information** : If you do not specify any mapping this method will resolve all the http request i.e. you can send `GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE` request to the specified url and it will be resolved.

For you case, you change just your controller to look like :

```
package com.example.demo.home;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @RestController
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping("/") // Or you can do : @GetMapping("/")
        public String home(){
            return "home";
        }

    }
```

The url:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code/configuration, it will look for the `html` file under `static` or `webapp` folder, meanwhile your home controller should return `home.html` not `home`.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf should be included in project's pom.xml as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also the home.html file should be moved from templates to static directory.

For more details have a look at [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).